# How server side page decide a request to a page is authorized?

Tags: php, html

It's normal case, user inputs a username with password, and after that the entire system can be accessed. Suppose I have a page a.php(or ASP), how can I restrict only the user that has been authorized can view a.php, for other user if they type (http://host/a.php) in browser, they will get an error?

And furthermore, is it done thru cookie? If you can explain the details under the hood I would appreciate more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Cookies but most PHP sites use Sessions.

See for detailed information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

The steps involved:

1.) Create a sign-in page that checks for valid username and password then save a key value to a session variable that references the user table.
signin.php (sudo-code)

```
session_start();

if(username is correct && password is correct)
{
  $_SESSION['userkey'] = GUID from database
}
```

2.) Create a PHP page that has the session variable and checks if the variable is set.

signincheck.php (sudo-code)

```
session_start();
$is_signed_in = false;

if (isset($_SESSION['userkey'])) 
{
    if(isvalid userkey)
    {
    $is_signed_in = true;
    }
}
```

3.) Require that page in each of your pages that needs to be for registered only.

```
require('signincheck.php');

if($is_signed_in === true)
{
  allow access to page
}
else
{
  header redirect to some other page
}
```

Comment: Is it easily to be attacked? If the session ID is stolen... And I thought the session is implemented by Cookie?

Comment: Nothing is 100% but a Cookie is stored on the client machine and a session is on the server so a session is more secure.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat **lengthy topic** and needs so much explanation to fit in this space. I'd advise you to go through the **following beginner level tutorials** on how to create a Login system with PHP. You will then understand what happens under the hood:

1. [PHP Simple Login Script Tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/workshopview.php?id=6)
   – Very details guide to create a PHP and MySQL login system.
2. [Creating a Secure PHP Login Script](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-Secure-PHP-Login-Script/) 
   – How to create a secure PHP login script that will allow safe authentication.
3. [Developing a Login System with PHP and MySQL](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/php-login-system-050531/)
   – another greate PHP and MySQL login tutorials.
4. [Login – Logout with a Session in 1 file](http://www.phpsimple.net/tutorials/login_logout/)
   – Write a php code for login and logout in one file.
5. [Creating a file based login system](http://www.phptoys.com/e107_plugins/content/content.php?content.35)
   – PHP Login system without mysql database
6. [Login system](http://www.azforums.net/index.php?showtopic=3680)
   – Learn to create a PHP and Mysql Login system by using cookie
7. [PHP Log In Script – video tutorial](http://www.dreamweaverclub.com/vtm/php-login-script.php)
   – Video Tutorials how to create a PHP and Mysql login system.

Comment: Thanks, but how to write a login is not the question I am asking, maybe my question is obscure, sorry about that. I am more backgound prone :)

Comment: @Bin, I am not asking you to create the login. I am suggesting to read these tutorials and you will clearly know *what's going under the hood.* :)

Comment: btw, is all the login implemented by cookie? How about the cookie is captured and reused by an attacker?